# Select records that do not start with "xxx" joined onto another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, sql-like

I am trying get a list of items (to eventually be deleted). My inner select returns the following items from the `collections` table (which is correct).

[image: Inner Select]

I want to use the above results to to join on the `files` table and select items that do not  start with the above path so I can then delete them.

I tried using this query to select them however, if I filter the results, the records that I wanted to exclude exist in the result set.

```sql
SELECT files.path, c.path FROM files LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT json_extract(info, '$.path') AS path FROM collections 
  WHERE 
  json_extract(info, '$.path') like 'C:/Users/untun/Documents%'
  AND json_extract(info, '$.path') != 'C:/Users/untun/Documents'
) AS c ON c.path LIKE files.path || '%'

-- Adding the next lines returns the two records below
-- GROUP BY files.path
-- HAVING files.path like 'C:/Users/untun/Documents/vscode/projects/csharp%'
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reverse the operands of the operator `LIKE` and filter out the rows that don't match in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT f.path 
FROM files AS f 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT json_extract(info, '$.path') AS path 
  FROM collections 
  WHERE json_extract(info, '$.path') LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents_%'
) AS c ON f.path LIKE c.path || '%'
WHERE c.path IS NULL;
```

Also, the condition:

```
json_extract(info, '$.path') like 'C:/Users/untun/Documents%'
AND 
json_extract(info, '$.path') != 'C:/Users/untun/Documents'
```

can be simplified to:

```
json_extract(info, '$.path') LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents_%'
```

Comment: I tried wrapping that in a `DELETE FROM files WHERE EXISTS (...)` but that deleted everything. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: NVM `DELETE FROM files WHERE files.path in (SELECT files.path FROM...)`

Comment: If I do `LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents/vscode/projects/csharp-tests_%'`, then everything gets deleted, even things in a different directory `C:/Users/untun/Documents/other/file.txt`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn the condition: `json_extract(info, '$.path') like 'C:/Users/untun/Documents%' AND json_extract(info, '$.path') != 'C:/Users/untun/Documents'` means that you want all rows where path starts with `'C:/Users/untun/Documents%'` but it also contains at least 1 more char, right? This is what `json_extract(info, '$.path') LIKE 'C:/Users/untun/Documents_%'` does.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn the `_` before `%` is a wildcard for exactly 1 (any) char.

Comment: `collections` is a list of folder roots. What I am trying to achieve, is to delete all `files` in that folder, unless the file is in another `collection`. So, if the file is in 2+ collections it wont be deleted otherwise it will be deleted. So, maybe my query approach is incorrect?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn my query is about the question as you posted it. As I said, I proposed the simplification in the WHERE clause of the subquery because of the conditions you use. Both ways are equivalent.

Comment: Okay since you answered the question, I will open a new question.